# Системный BEEP проигрывается через колонки / наушники, но не через бипер на материнской плате

Tags: windows, windows-10, аудио, материнская-плата

Решил немного по ретро удариться и купил бипер.
Вот такой:

[image: Фото внутреннего динамика подсоединяемого к плате компьютера]

Подсоединил красный провод к +5v на пинах материнки, а второй к "*Speaker*". В общем, работает при включении компьютера, когда BIOS показывает POST, пищит однократно.

Так вот вопрос.
Если использовать в Windows beeper, например через:

```ps
powershell.exe [console]::beep(500,600)
```

Звук идёт либо через колонки либо через наушники. Хочу, чтобы звук шёл из динамика на плате, как это сделать?

###### Система:

| Наименование | Значение |
| --- | --- |
| Edition | Windows 10 Pro |
| Version | 21H1 |
| OS build | 19043.928 |
| Experience | Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.3530.0 |
| MotherBoard | Asus Maximus IV Extreme-Z |

P.S. Понимаю, что вопрос не совсем про программирование, больше подходит для SuperUser, вопрос там [задан](https://superuser.com/questions/1805668/system-beep-runs-through-desktop-speakers-i-want-the-motherboard-beeper), но пока ответа нет, попробую и здесь.

Comment: Вероятно, вопрос на SuperUser является дубликатом [этого вопроса](https://superuser.com/questions/1790338) (правда, ответ там нерабочий)

Comment: @andreymal не совсем дубликат, Ctrl + G (^G) первое что находится в интернете и это не выдаёт звук даже из настольных динамиков. Там в комментах подсказали ссылку на драйвер, который ругается на вирус, попробую, возможно действительно решит. UPD: вопрос да, дублирует.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение найдено.
Как указано в комментариях на SuperUser, [этот ответ](https://superuser.com/questions/227939/how-to-make-the-pc-speaker-beep-from-the-windows-7-command-prompt/451501#451501) помог, **BEEPX** работает. Он заменяет драйвер `beep.sys` на рабочий. Причем с подписью Microsoft.

Ссылки на драйвер:
[x86](https://www.waldbauer.com/tmp/dl.php?download=beepx) | [x64](https://www.waldbauer.com/tmp/dl.php?download=beepxp64).

На случай, если сайт не работает, вот резервные ссылки на Gdrive:
[x86](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UkFJ3fdchDJQlV9Axxfg4TJNeJNscOmS/view?usp=drive_link) | [x64](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13SQw2xUCp3Vs0bJxp7V7JbsPawgsBAvE/view?usp=drive_link).

Публикуя эти резервные ссылки, я не нарушаю лицензию, как указано внутри:

> ### License
>
> This Application and Sourcecode may be distributed freely.
> The Sourcecode is Licensed in Terms of the GNU GPL v3.
> See: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html

### Hashsums:

|  | beepx.zip (x86) | beepx64.zip (x64) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Size: | 71803 bytes (70 KiB) | 26868 bytes (26 KiB) |
| CRC32: | 4766B287 | 6DB259A4 |
| CRC64: | 5158EE3F09D4E4BE | 2B08DC7BCDB37D51 |
| SHA256: | A7F9ED13D1D165482BA9E8A78CD02A48FD8BEC53A4886ECE8B24AD02F60131F8 | C36E4E4B34FB99C90A66C115140C59A75980CEACC01F1542421B226A191D53EE |
| SHA1: | 3681907BA22FCB107839CFB17A72CE3B84C96FAA | BA6548D98A07634FB9D23BDEC2989BF6FB3B0558 |
| BLAKE2sp: | 7567A439B1F789E441D33CD69104F5AC49B621D055332148C8DF924316E66DEB | 45B69757948A15C29EAE618EB335581539BFAC2F83B64E610969237EBF4FE0DF |

## Благодарности:

- Людвигу Эртлю, автору **beepx**
- [@andrew-morton](https://superuser.com/users/272824/andrew-morton) за указание на тему с работающим [ответом](https://superuser.com/questions/227939/how-to-make-the-pc-speaker-beep-from-the-windows-7-command-prompt/451501#451501)
- [@canopee](https://superuser.com/users/147333/canopee) за размещение [ответа](https://superuser.com/questions/227939/how-to-make-the-pc-speaker-beep-from-the-windows-7-command-prompt/451501#451501) и [@rustyx](https://superuser.com/users/85760/rustyx) за [предоставление ссылки на x64](https://superuser.com/questions/227939/how-to-make-the-pc-speaker-beep-from-the-windows-7-command-prompt/451501#comment1752316_451501)
- [@andreymal](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178213/andreymal) за указание на [похожий вопрос](https://superuser.com/questions/1790338/is-it-possible-to-cause-the-physical-pc-speaker-to-beep-in-windows-10), который я пропустил, однако он не содержит рабочего решения, в любом случае, спасибо за [комментарий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1537503/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-beep-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%83%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5#comment2764336_1537503) и готовность помочь